# Поясните, пожалуйста, правило

Tags: сказуемые, определения, подлежащее

У Розенталя в правилах о согласованных определениях встречается следующее, с приведеннымми примерами:

*Не обособляются распространенные определения, связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого они входят: В марте зерно лежало ссыпанное в закрома (С.‑Щ.) — дело не в том, что зерно лежало, а в том, что оно было ссыпано в закрома (в этих случаях в определительном обороте может быть употреблена форма творительного падежа: лежало ссыпанным в закрома); Аккуратный старичок ходил вооружённый дождевым зонтом.

Обычно такие конструкции образуются с глаголами движения или состояния, выступающими в роли знаменательной связки. Ср. с глаголом другой семантики: Елизавета молчала, испуганная и взволнованная (А. Т.).

Если глагол со значением движения или состояния сам по себе служит сказуемым, то определительный оборот обособляется: Трифон Иваныч выиграл у меня два рубля с полтиной и ушёл, весьма довольный своей победой (Т.); Перерыв ещё не кончился, а она уже стояла у станка, побледневшая, гладенько причёсанная (Ник.); И она пошла рядом со мною, кряжистая, уверенная в своей силе (Гл.);*

Поясните, пожалуйста, что значит "глагол служит сам по себе сказуемым", то есть, когда определительный оборот обособляется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта задача не такая простая. Даже если определение относится к глаголу движения или состояния, оно может входить в сказуеое, а может быть обособленным.

Определяется это по структуре предложения.

(1) *Трифон Иваныч выиграл у меня два рубля с полтиной и ушёл, весьма довольный своей победой* (обособленное определение)

(2) *Трифон Иваныч выиграл у меня два рубля с полтиной и ушёл весьма довольный* (оборот входит в сказуемое).

В первом предложении ударение падает на слово *ушёл* (на этом предложении можно закончить), а оборот сообщает нам дополнительную информацию.

Во втором предложении ударение падает на оборот, обособить его сложно, структура предложения при обособлении получится неуравновешенной, неудобной для чтения.

Другие парные варианты:

*Дети отправились  в путь  бодрые и весёлые.  Опечаленный пришёл я домой и положил браунинг на прежнее место.*

*Дети, бодрые и весёлые, отправились  путь.  Опечаленный, я пришёл домой и положил браунинг на прежнее место.*

ВЫВОД. Фактически при решении этой задачи мы определяем, удобно ли нам включить оборот в основное предложение, сделав его сказуемым, или удобнее его обособить. Это зависит от распространенности оборота и от его позиции в предложении.

Answer (score 1):

"Служит сам по себе сказуемым" означает, что глагол "имеет законченный смысл, выражая *содержание* действия", о котором в предложении говорится. В нашем же случае содержание действия не сводится к глаголу "лежать", оно в том, что зерно *пребывает* в некотором состоянии, *имеет* определённую форму хранения - глагол выполняет *вспомогательную* функцию, приписывая зерну такое состояние.

Answer (score 0):

Уж не знаю, что Вас здесь смутило. Если Вы достаточно внимательно изучали тему "Составное именное сказуемое", то должны знать следующую особенность:

"Глагол-связка при составном именном сказуемом может иметь собственное лексическое значение, выражающее **движение, состояние, или деятельность**".
Также такие глаголы могут быть **простыми глагольными сказуемыми** и иметь собственную смысловую нагрузку, что и имеет в виду Розенталь.